# How to send mail from JSP page in Spring (AWS Codestar)?

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-mail, aws-codestar

Using AWS Codestar I am trying to send emails directly from JSP but getting errors in every method does anyone have any idea of how to send mail in spring

Comment: Don't do it from a JSP. A JSP is a view component. The responsibility of the view is to display the model prepared by the controller. Not to send emails. How to send mails is described in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#mail

Comment: Where is the JSP code and the error you got?